# Chromosome naming convention: Why are there chromosomes named "1" and "1A"?

Tags: genetics, chromosome

I've been stumbling on multiple genome of birds where there is a "1A" chromosome and a "1" chromosome. [For example, the zebra finch has](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome?term=taeniopygia%20guttata) 1A and 4A. What does that mean?

Do you have any resource about naming conventions for chromosomes and if this naming convention is specific to birds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking at some of the reference genome papers. My guess is that the chromosomes are named as such based on their synteny to the chicken genome; e.g. look at Accessory Figure 3 [here](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fnature08819/MediaObjects/41586_2010_BFnature08819_MOESM18_ESM.pdf) for your zebra finch, and note that chromsomes 1 and 4 are split in the zebra finch relative to Gallus.

The direct comparison from that paper is to an Accessory Table 1 that I can't actually find.

I would guess that in most cases it's because of a synteny comparison to some reference, in this case chicken that splits a chromosome in the new genome. For example sequences homologous to the chicken chr1 are on two finch chromosomes 1 and 1A.

Comment: This is my suspicion as well, similar to the ape chromosomes 2A and 2B.